# Convert RDM to VMDK on-the-fly

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a RAID setup in which I also have a virtual volume consisting of two 3TB drives. I have the resulting 6TB drive mapped to a virtual machine in ESXi 5.5 through Raw Device Mapping. However, I will need to convert that drive to a VMDK on the same drive.

In other words, how do I convert a raw disk to a VMDK and save it on the same drive? Is this even possible?

Comment: Google found me this; http://virtualizationtechno.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/converting-rdm-disk-to-vmdk.html

Comment: "B.5.select the destination datastore" - It's the disk I actually want to convert, so that won't really work this way...

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.  You can P2V a live system, you can use a partition manager to copy an offline system but either way it must be from one drive to another.

With thin provisioned VMDKs you only need space for the actual data, which could make it much easier if the RDM drive is mostly empty.